# Unresponsive mouse wheel on macOS Sierra

Tags: mouse, macos

Since I upgraded to Sierra, mouse wheel scrolling has become a lot worse. When I scroll the wheel fast, it behaves like it did before and scrolls a bunch of lines, but when I scroll the wheel one notch at a time, nothing happens.

I use a Steelseries Sensei gaming mouse but I also tested with a basic Dell mouse. (There's no model number on it.) As of macOS 10.12.1, this issue affects all programs.

Are there any workarounds? Please don't suggest USB Overdrive or any other nagware.

Edit: [I found a video (not me) which shows the issue perfectly. Clearly it's not just me.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkVNwk2SOzo)

Comment: What's frustrating is that this started happening in the Sierra public beta 2, in July, and I reported it via the feedback assistant. But even on the latest Sierra 10.12.1 beta 3, the issue still persists.

Comment: @bgeer proposed edit: I think this changed in the 10.12.1 update. Single ticks of the mouse wheel no longer work for me in any program either. Updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked for many solutions and [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html), is the only one that I've found that fixes it. Would love to hear if there are others, because I agree the nagware aspect is annoying (although it's only on boot, so it's not actually that bad).

Install it, then, in the settings, set "Wheel up" to scroll up "2 lines" and "Wheel down" to scroll down "2 lines". For whatever reason you have to use "2 lines"—"one line" still exhibits the issue. It's possible your mouse will require different settings.

Comment: OP specifically said "Please don't suggest USB Overdrive."

Comment: @tubedogg I agree the nagware aspect of USB Overdrive is annoying, but it's the only solution I've found. What should I do then? Open a new question that's exactly identical except without this restriction, and post my answer there? Would that not get closed as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: Honestly in that case I post a comment saying "I know you said no USB Overdrive, but the only solution I could find was XYZ". Answers should generally address the question within the bounds that the OP sets. Sometimes that's impossible, and that's why we have unanswered questions - but if it's only impossible _because of the OP's parameters_, we should be telling the OP that through comments. They may change their parameters and then the answer would be posted. Answers that explicitly ignore the OP's requirements tend to get downvoted or flamed, depending on who sees it.

Comment: As far USB Overdrive's "nagware aspect" being annoying, my reaction is generally "That's because you didn't buy the software." Some people want free solutions only, and that's fine, but unless one is willing to write the software themselves, there's only so far one can go in being picky while begging (i.e. beggars can't be choosers).

Comment: @tubedogg but the point of this site (as with all SE sites) is to help anyone with the same problem, not just the OP. I'll edit my answer, but IMO in general restrictions like this are bad for the site because they exclude answers that could help other people (in particular if this answer were already here before from someone else it would have saved me a lot of trouble).

Comment: I understand what you're saying. My thought on that is, if someone finds the question through a search, already knowing they (like the OP) don't want to use USB Overdrive, read the question to find out the OP is on the same page, and then finds the only answer is to use USB Overdrive, how much has that helped? That's why I suggested adding it as a comment. Also, please don't mistake what I say for restrictions. I don't own this site and I'm not even a moderator. I'm simply stating what I would've done in this situation and explaining my reasoning.

Comment: @tubedogg re: "That's because you didn't buy the software." In this case, basic functionality has been broken by an OS update. I shouldn't have to pay to make it work as designed. I'm normally okay with paid software but in this case it comes across as 'price gougey.' I get that this has become the only valid topic about this particular mouse wheel issue so I'll upvote it but I can't accept it.

Comment: it breaks some other aspects like hovering when cmd+tab is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this guy made an invisible app wich solves a problem.
https://github.com/yolcu/discrete-scroll
Runs in background and scroll 3 lines on tick.

Comment: I'll check this out when I'm at my Mac tonight. Thanks!